# Google Bookmarks Discontinued -- How to get old bookmarks back?

Tags: google-bookmarks

How can I get back my old bookmarks from Google Bookmarks, which has recently been discontinued?

The [website](https://google.com/bookmarks) is completely gone:

[image]

Is the data stored anywhere? I tried looking in [Google MyAccount](https://myaccount.google.com/) and couldn't find it there either.